# JST to mini USB- Is it possible, how would this work?

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-design, adafruit

Rather than using a mini USB cable to charge the [NANO V3.0 Development Board - Clone Compatible Model](https://www.electronicscomp.com/nano-v3.0-development-board-clone-compatible-model), I want to use a lithium ion battery pack. Like this one [here](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1578). How would I connect the two? Would I use a cable adapter between JST and mini USB?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome,

To do what you want, you could indeed use a battery pack with a JST to mini USB cable similar to [this one](https://www.starte-cable.com/usb-2-0-cable/mini-b-usb-2-0-cable/jst-ph-2-0-4-pin-to-mini-usb-5-pin-male-cable.html). The tricky part is finding the right cable with a 2 pins JST connector only (since you just want to power up your device).

Moreover, be careful with your battery pack, it's only a 3.7V and you will need at least a 7V battery pack to supply your development board.

Comment: Alternatively, cut a USB cable in half and put your own JST connector on it.

Comment: "Moreover, be careful with your battery pack, it's only a 3.7V and you will need at least a 7V battery pack to supply your development board." How would I achieve this since there are no lithium ion polymer packs that can provide 7v for the development board, how would I do this?

Comment: "Moreover, be careful with your battery pack, it's only a 3.7V and you will need at least a 7V battery pack to supply your development board." How would I achieve this since there are no lithium ion polymer packs that can provide 7v for the development board, I am trying to connect that development board voltage (7v) with wireless charging I was going to use these components--https://www.adafruit.com/product/1905 and https://www.adafruit.com/product/1901 in order to make the wireless charging rechargeable battery to then connect to this development board.  How could I do this?

Comment: would connect something like this work?---https://www.amazon.ca/Wireless-Receiver-Interface-Direction-Ultra-Thin/dp/B07W62CW55

Comment: But I want to add a form of battery so it can be used when taken off charge, so the wireless charger charges the battery pack which then us used to provide power to the development board

Comment: How do you want to perform a wireless charging with this battery ? do you have already a device for that ?